# Make maximum likelihood program byable in Stata

Tags: stata

I want to make my ml program ( `ado` file) `byable` (i.e. allow the use of `by`). For that purpose, I was going through [Maximum Likelihood Estimation with Stata](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/maximum-likelihood-estimation-stata/) third edition to see whether I need to take special consideration for ml program, other than those mentioned in programming [manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/pbyable.pdf). In p. 170 of the book, the author suggests the reader to look into the manual. So, I was wondering whether we need to take special consideration (other than that mentioned in the manual)for making the ml program `byable`

Comment: I'd ask why you want to do this. A major consequence would be that only the results for the last estimation remain accessible after fitting. For many purposes that would be problematic. If you want to fit a given model repeatedly to different groups, use the machinery provided by statsby instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any programming project there are a milion things and more that can go wrong, so there can never be a guarantee that there is not something specific about your maximum likelihood program that breaks things. However, in general you should be fine. I copy the relevant top part of a program Nick, Stephen Jenkins and I have written some time ago (`betafit`), that makes `betafit` "byable".

```
/*------------------------------------------------ playback request */
program betafit, eclass byable(onecall)
        ...
        if replay() {
                if "`e(cmd)'" != "betafit" {
                        di as err "results for betafit not found"
                        exit 301
                }
                if _by() error 190 
                Display `0'
                exit `rc'
        }
        if _by() by `_byvars'`_byrc0': Estimate `0'
        else Estimate `0'
end

/*------------------------------------------------ estimation */
program Estimate, eclass byable(recall)
     ...
```

Comment: @ Maarten:Thank you for the reference.